# Given array of 1000 strings wih an associated time-interval value X for each, how do I perform a task for each of the strings, every x minutes?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have a thousand (for example, could be more) strings and for each string, there is a field associated with it which represents *time interval*.

For each one of the strings, I need to perform a task which takes the string as input and produces some output, every `X` minutes (`X` being the time interval mentioned above).

If it was a single value of time interval for all the strings, then I would set up a single cron job and that would suffice; but I have a different value of time interval for each of the strings.

So I'll set up a thousand or more cron jobs. That does not feel right. So what would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: if I understand this correctly you want to do something with a string then sleep (https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) some `x` time and go to the next string ?

Comment: Does sleep really work if it's minutes? Doesn't the browser just kill the connection then?

Comment: How accurate does it have to be with this "X" time between the runs?

Comment: @Edwin Nooo. I have 1000 strings, and for each of them,I have to perform some task each X minutes (this goes on forever), such that X is different for each string. ADDED COMPLICATION: The task for each string has to be performed asynchronously/simultaneously. In other words, the tasks for all the strings should be fired/started at (almost) the same time (A difference of a few seconds is OK)

Comment: @Andreas it can be a cron job that does the whole sleep thing

Comment: @Andreas  I don't thing `sleep()` is needed anywhere here. I have 1000 strings, and for each of them,I have to perform some task each X minutes (this goes on forever), such that X is different for each string. ADDED COMPLICATION: The task for each string has to be performed asynchronously/simultaneously. In other words, the tasks for all the strings should be fired/started at (almost) the same time (A difference of a few seconds is OK)

Comment: @Edwin you don't think the owner of the cron service gets a little pissed if he's cron is sleeping all the time?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Laravel Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling), even only to inspire you. Basically, a php script runs every minute via cronjob that handles the schedule. You can add jobs to the schedule with something like `$schedule->job(new Heartbeat)->everyFiveMinutes();`. Just a thought

Comment: The only option I can think of is that you build your own "cron" service being a browers that is open on a page and the page refresh with meta refresh tag. "All" you need to do is create a an array with times of when the browser should refresh and (trigger the PHP script) and use the time as the countdown in the meta refresh.

Comment: @kerbholz but it's not always the same time between the runs if I understand it correct, say you have one that should run every three minutes and one every five that means in 10 minutes you have done five runs.

Comment: @Andreas Add a job schedule for every job then: `$schedule->job(JOBX)->everyFiveMinutes(); $schedule->job(JOBY)->everyMinute();`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using a library that already did this instead of re-inventing the wheel yourself.

https://packagist.org/packages/peppeocchi/php-cron-scheduler

But, if you'd really want to code it yourself you'll need to have "two variables" one with last executed which has to be read from a file or database in between execution cycles, one with interval and have cron call your script every second/minute

Take a look at the proof of concept code here. Untested but it should point you in to how it should work in theory.

```
class Job 
{
    protected $interval = 0;
    protected $lastrun = 0;
    protected $job = null; 
    protected $filename = null;   

    public function __construct($id, $interval,callable $job) 
    {
         $this->interval = $interval;
         $this->job = $job;
         $this->filename = __DIR__.'/'.$id.'.job';
         $this->lastrun = file_get_contents($this->filename) ? : 0;
    }

    public function attemptRun($time) 
    {
       if($time - $this->lastrun >= $this->interval) {
           $this->run($time);
       }
    }

    protected function run($time) 
    {
         file_put_contents($this->filename, $time);
         $this->job();
    }

}

$jobs = [
   new Job('addition', 10, function() { $a = 1; $b = 2; $c = $a + $b;}),
   new Job('subtraction', 20, function() { $a = 1; $b = 2; $c = $a - $b;}),
];

var $currentTime = time();
foreach($jobs as $job) {
   $job->attemptRun($currentTime);
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, this script will run the job only once after the `$interval` time has passed. I need to keep running the jobs at regular intervals

Comment: @JBel that is a regular interval... every 10 and 20 seconds the job runs if you have it triggered by cron every second. on the first run all jobs will run, then the interval timer kicks in.

Answer (score 1):

**Cron job**: Run it every minute.

Let's say you have 3 strings in the format **string_value-execute after certain minutes**-

- some_string-5
- some_string_2-10
- some_string_3-15

So, execution time if we start from 0 will have a series like this-

- 0
- 5  (execute first)
- 10 (execute first as well as second string)
- 15 (execute first and third string)
- 20 (execute first as well as second string)
- 25 (execute only first)
- 30 (execute first,second,third)

**Database part:**

Have 2 tables.

- First table- has a single column having current cron minute.
- second table- Have column as string , interval duration , next_execution_time

Now, insert into first table whenever you run it. 
Secondly, do a "Select * from table_name where next_execution_time = current_got_fetched_from_first_table".

**Introduce new strings**- When you are doing so, insert as `first start interval =  current_cron_time + interval_duration to execute`.

P.S- When processing completes, you also need to update the second table with their respective `next_execution_time`.